# Crear plantilla en script usando JavaScript puro sin librerías

Tags: javascript, html, html5, template

Quiero crear un sistema simple de plantillas usando JavaScript puro, **sin librerías de ningún tipo**, para que se procese la página y luego con una función JavaScript simple pueda cargar las diferentes secciones de la página. Pero no consigo dar con la tecla para que funcione.

Tengo este código (simplificado):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll("#menu").length == 0) {
    var script = document.querySelector("#script-menu");
    var html = script.innerHTML;
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(html);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Ir al menú</button>

<script type="text/html" id="script-menu">
  <div class="vista" id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

Pero cuando pulso el botón, en lugar de añadir el menú a la ventana, lo que hace es que me lanza este mensaje de error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Lo cual tiene sentido porque la variable `html` contiene una cadena de texto y no un `Node`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para leer/procesar el contenido del `script` como si fuera un `Node` en lugar de una cadena?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `appendChild` es para añadir nodos, no una cadena `HTML`. Si deseas añadir el template al `body` y reemplazar todo lo que se encuentra dentro de este, puedes usar [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = html;
```

Pero si lo que deseas es añadir el contenido al final de lo que ya se encuentra en el `body`, puedes usar el método [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```

Aquí te dejo tu mismo snippet con la variación:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (document.querySelectorAll("#menu").length == 0) {
    var script = document.querySelector("#script-menu");
    var html = script.innerHTML;
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Ir al menú</button>

<script type="text/html" id="script-menu">
  <div class="vista" id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Es lo que buscaba, ¿sabes si el soporte para navegadores en Android/iOS es bueno?

Comment: Sí, es soportado. `insertAdjacentHTML` es soportado por la mayoría de los navegadores. [Aquí](http://caniuse.com/#search=insertAdjacentHTML) puedes ampliar más detalles.